# Jenkins job failure email in stage

Tags: jenkins

pipeline {
agent any

```
stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
            // Checkout your code from version control system
            checkout scm
        }
    }

    stage('Modify Text File') {
        steps {
            script {
                // Set the path to your project directory
                def projectDir = "path/to/your/project"

                // Navigate to the project directory
                dir(projectDir) {
                    // Path to the source directory
                    def sourceDir = "source"

                    // Path to the text file
                    def textFilePath = "${sourceDir}/yourfile.txt"

                    // Read the content of the file
                    def fileContent = readFile(file: textFilePath).trim()

                    // Add the new line at line number 6
                    def newLine = "Your new line content"
                    fileContent = fileContent.split('\n').insert(5, newLine).join('\n')

                    // Write the modified content back to the file
                    writeFile(file: textFilePath, text: fileContent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Add more stages as needed
}

// Post-build actions, notifications, etc.
post {
    // Add post-build actions if necessary
}
```

}
Replace "path/to/your/project" and "Your new line content" with your actual project path and the content you want to add. This pipeline assumes you have a file named yourfile.txt in a directory named source within your project. Adjust paths and file names according to your project structure.

Comment: Hi, looks like something went wrong here? did someone edit the original question post instead of opening a newe post to answer here?